# ODBC PHP / Oracle - UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE

Tags: php, sql, oracle

Estou em um projeto usando PHP e Oracle. a conexão está OK, com esse código eu consigo executar todos os selects que eu preciso normalmente, o que eu não consigo executar são `INSERTS`, `UPDATES` e `DELETE`.

Alguém saberia me dizer o porquê?

```
<?php
require_once('connection.php');
if($conn)
{
   $Query = "UPDATE PQAQ SET CAMINHO_ARQUIVO = 'PDF' WHERE CODIGO_PROCESSO = 18 AND CAMINHO_ARQUIVO = 'TESTE.PHP'";
   odbc_exec($conn, $Query);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alguns bancos trabalham com trasação em duas fazes por padrão. Caso alteração (insert/update/delete) seja executada ela não é colocada em 'prática' na hora, fica pendente até o commit.

Existem duas formas de resolver esse o problema. A primeira é enviar o commit manualmente com a função [odbc_commit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-commit.php).

```
$Query = "UPDATE PQAQ SET CAMINHO_ARQUIVO = 'PDF' 
          WHERE CODIGO_PROCESSO = 18 AND CAMINHO_ARQUIVO = 'TESTE.PHP'";
odbc_exec($conn, $Query);

if(!odbc_commit($conn)){
    echo 'erro: '. odbc_errormsg($conn);
}
```

A segunda é deixar o odbc trabalhar em autocommit por padrão, a função [odbc_autocommit()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-autocommit.php) faz isso deixa sua chamada logo após a criação da conexão.

```
odbc_autocommit($conn, true);
```

Comment: Ainda não consegue se comunicar com o banco :( existe uma maneira de saber se a Query foi executada pelo ODBC? Algo como um ODBC_result? algo do tipo.

Comment: @RafaelBrito `odbc_commit()` retorna erro ou false?

Comment: Eu adicionei ODBC_commit() abaixo do meu código apenas, ele não retornou em nada.

Comment: @RafaelBrito faz lá `if(odbc_commit($conn)){ echo 'sucesso'; }else { print_r(odbc_errormsg($conn));}`

Comment: Ele retorna 'sucesso', mas o banco não atualiza. Eu revisei a tabela, a sintaxe, no Oracle Development a sintaxe está executa normalmente. O que mais poderia ser?

Comment: @RafaelBrito Antes do primeiro if coloque `odbc_autocommit($conn, true);` agora deve gravar no banco a alteração.

Comment: o ODBC_exec($conn, $Query), depois das alterações que você me indicou, está travando a página PHP. Ela não chega nem gerar mais o 'sucesso'.

Comment: fiz todos os testes, o ODBC_exec, quando passa uma sintaxe que roda em banco, ele trava a pagina PHP. Eu tiro uma virgula da $Query, e ele roda normalmente. O que leva o ODBC_exec travar?

Comment: @RafaelBrito vou dar uma olhada aqui. Por curiosidade a extensão do oracle pq vc não usa no lugar do odbc?

Comment: Era probleminha interno do server mesmo, rodou certinho o que você me indicou. Muito obrigado.